# Error in if: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am trying to create a bracketing function and using the following code in R:

```
y<-function(x){x^2+2*x}

a<--1
b<-1

alpha<-(sqrt(5)-1)/2
e<-0.001

bracketing<-function(f, a, b, c, top, result){
  if (f(a) > f(b)) {
    return(result)
  }
  else if(top==1){
    c<-b + alpha*(b-a)
  }
  result[top,]<-c(a, b, c)
  if (f(b) < f(c)) {
    a<-b
    b<-c
    c<-b + alpha*(b-a)
  }
  else if (f(b) > f(c)) {
    a<-b
    b<-c
    c<-b + alpha*(b-a) 
  }
  result<-bracketing(f, a, b, c, top=top+1, result)
  return(result)
}

result<-data.frame(a=rep(NA), b=rep(NA), c=rep(NA))
result<-bracketing(y, NA, NA, NA, 1, result)
```

I received this error message in if function:

```
Error in if (f(a) > f(b)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

How do I prevent it?

Comment: The error message is pretty helpful in this case. When calculating `(f(a) > f(b))` you get an `NA` (missing) value returned instead of a `TRUE` or `FALSE`, probably due to either `a` and/or `b` being `NA`. In the same way that `1 > NA` returns `NA`

Comment: See `if(NA) 1` - You need to find out why your `if()` condition returns NA

Comment: both your `a` and `b`'s are `NA` : `bracketing(y, NA, NA, NA, 1, result)`